# How to get integer from list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer

I have this list of lists:

```
lst =[[5,5,5,5],[5,0,1,5],[5,0,3,5],[5,2,3,5],[5,5,5,5]]
```

And I need some kind of function for search one particular number (e.g.1) where the output would be something like this:

```
 >>> It's in a list with index 1
 >>> In list with index 1, it has index 2
```

Or even something more simple like:

```
>>> 1
>>> 2
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that's a bit more concise and seems more practical to me:

```
def find_int(l, target):
    sub_list = [x for x in range(len(l)) if target in l[x]][0]
    return sub_list, l[sub_list].index(target)


>>> lst = [[5,5,5,5],[5,0,1,5],[5,0,3,5],[5,2,3,5],[5,5,5,5]]
>>> print(find_int(lst,2))
(3, 1)
```

Here's a version with the cute text that returns exactly like you specified:

```
def find_int(l, target):
    for sub_list in range(len(l)):
        if target in l[sub_list]:
            print("It's in a list with index " + str(sub_list))
            print("In list with index " + str(sub_list) + ", it has index " + str(l[sub_list].index(target)))
            return

>>> lst = [[5,5,5,5],[5,0,1,5],[5,0,3,5],[5,2,3,5],[5,5,5,5]]
>>> find_int(lst,2)
It's in a list with index 3                                                                                                                    
In list with index 1, it has index 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only remaining problem is that I'm using numpy and then it returns: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'. Do you have any suggestion how to maybe convert array back to list?